# How to display capital cities of checked countries in a multiple arraylist in an alertdialog using java

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android studio programming. I wish to display checked country capitol cities from the second arraylist in another alertdialog. The following is my java code.
Please help me how to retrive the countries individual capitol cities

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<CharSequence> list = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    List<CharSequence> list2 = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //for (int i=0;i<6;){
        list.add(0, "Kenya");
        list.add(1, "Uganda");
        list.add(2, "Tanzania");
        list.add(3, "S.Sudan");
        list.add(4, "Rwanda");

        list2.add(0, "Nairobi");
        list2.add(1, "Kampala");
        list2.add(2, "Der-es-salaam");
        list2.add(3, "Juba");
        list2.add(4, "Kigali");

        View button = (View) findViewById(R.id.btnFindCapitol);
        assert button != null;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Intialize  readable sequence of char values
                final CharSequence[] diagCountryList=  list.toArray(new       CharSequence[list.size()]);
            //final CharSequence[] diagCapitolList = list2.toArray(new CharSequence[list2.size()]);
            final AlertDialog.Builder countryDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            final AlertDialog.Builder capitolDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            countryDialog.setTitle("Select Item");
            int count = diagCountryList.length;
            boolean[] is_checked = new boolean[count];

            // Creating multiple selection by using setMutliChoiceItem method
            countryDialog.setMultiChoiceItems(diagCountryList, is_checked,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton, boolean isChecked) {
                        }
                    });
            countryDialog.setCancelable(false);
            countryDialog.setPositiveButton("Capitol cities",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ListView list = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                            //Apply logic here
                            StringBuilder cityBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
                                boolean checked = list.isItemChecked(i);
                                //if more than one item is checked separate them
                                if (checked) {
                                    if (cityBuilder.length() > 0) cityBuilder.append("\n"+"\n");
                                       cityBuilder.append(list.getItemAtPosition(i));
                                }
                            }
                        /*Check string builder is empty or not. If string    builder is not empty.
                          It will display on the screen.
                         */
                                if (cityBuilder.toString().trim().equals("")) {
                                    capitolDialog.setMessage("Nothing was     selected");
                                    capitolDialog.show();

                                    //stringBuilder.setLength(0);
                                }/* else if     (cityBuilder.toString().trim().equals("")) {
                                    capitolDialog.setTitle("The city");
                                    capitolDialog.setMessage(cityBuilder);
                                    capitolDialog.show();

                                }*/else  {
                                    capitolDialog.setTitle("The cities");
                                    capitolDialog.setMessage(cityBuilder);
                                    capitolDialog.show();

                                }
                            }
                        });
                countryDialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int     which) {
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = countryDialog.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing that? If I were you, I would use a hashmap or hashtable, using the number as key, and an array of Strings as value.

Comment: I dont know how to do that boss.. send me a sample code that does/uses harshmaps in my example code.

Comment: Do:
HashMap<Int, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Int, List<String>>();/*start;*/  
     ArrayList <String>test = new ArrayList<String>();/*create aux*/
     test.add("uganda");
     test.add("Kampala");
   map.put(1, test);/*adding city and country 1*/  
   Do this in a bucle for everyone, and you got the HashMap working

Comment: I've putted an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Do the next, I've put comments for you to understand:

```
HashMap<Int, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Int, List<String>>();/*start;*/  
     ArrayList <String>test = new ArrayList<String>();/*create aux*/
     test.add("uganda");
     test.add("Kampala");
   map.put(1, test);/*adding city and country 1*/  
   //Do this in a bucle for everyone, and you got the HashMap working
  //to get
   map.get(1);
```

Now you have a structure like: [1:{"uganda","Kampala"}], do a bucle to apply this to your case, and you will have a hashMap with all the numbers linked to the cities and countries, like this one, and just getting using the number as key, it will return the names as Value.